# Django UpdateView update filed in view

Tags: python, django

I am making simple app in django, I have UpdateView for updating my model once is in the database. I update form I didn't include all fields I would like to update some of them in the background. 
Something like:

```
#...
invoice.organization = request.user.groups.first()
invoice.user_input = self.request.user.get_full_name()
invoice.price = form.cleaned_data['price'] #i update this field in UpdateView
invoice.quantity = form.cleaned_data['quantity']#i update this field in UpdateView

#this is what I do in form where I create my model I would like to do something like that in UpdateView too
if form.cleaned_data['price'] is not None and form.cleaned_data['quantity'] is not None:
     invoice.sum_price = float(form.cleaned_data['price']) * float(form.cleaned_data['quantity'])
else:
     invoice.sum_price = form.cleaned_data['price'] 
#...
```

This is how my UpdateView looks like:

```
class InvoiceUpdate(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.UpdateView):
    login_url = '/accounts/login'
    redirect_field_name = 'redirect_to'

    success_url = '/'

    template_name = 'invoice/invoice_update.html'

    model = Invoice

    fields = [
        'number',
        'price',
        'quantity',
        'comment',
        'notes',
    ]
```

How can I know update fields in UpdateView class?

Answer (score 0):

You can add this under your update view. It will updates the value for `organization` and `user_input` before saving to the database.

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    narocilnica = form.save(commit=False)
    narocilnica.organization = request.user.groups.first()
    narocilnica.user_input = self.request.user.get_full_name()
    if form.cleaned_data['price'] is not None and form.cleaned_data['quantity'] is not None:
        narocilnica.sum_price = float(form.cleaned_data['price']) * float(form.cleaned_data['quantity'])
    else:
        narocilnica.sum_price = form.cleaned_data['cena_brez_DDV'] 
    narocilnica = narocilnica.save()
    return self.success_url
```

Edit: Not sure what is `cena_brez_DDV` as it is not a field in the form, so you might get error for not having cleaned_data for that.

Comment: Now I get this error: if response.get('X-Frame-Options') is not None:
AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'get'